# Create a list name column in a list of data frames

Tags: r

Data:

```
 vec.1 <- c(1, 2)
 vec.2 <- c(2, 3)
 df.1 <- data.frame(vec.1, vec.2)
 df.2 <- data.frame(vec.2, vec.1)
 my_list <- list(df.1, df.2)
```

I wish to create a list number column that sequences along each data frame
indicating from which list they came from.

printing data list :

```
    [[1]]
   vec.1 vec.2
1     1     2
2     2     3

[[2]]
   vec.2 vec.1
1     2     1
2     3     2
```

Code:

```
funk <- function(x){
  index <- seq(x)
  linenum <- 
  cbind(x,index,linenum)
}

new.dat <- lapply(my_list, funk)
```

expected output :

```
[[1]]
  vec.1 vec.2 index listnum
1     1     2     1   1
2     2     3     2   1

[[2]]
  vec.2 vec.1 index listnum
1     2     1     1   2
2     3     2     2   2
```

currently I am facing difficulty creating this `listnum` column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `transform` to create the sequence column by looping through the `list` element and then the 'listnum' based on the sequence of `length` of 'my_list' with `Map`

```
Map(cbind, lapply(my_list, function(x) 
         transform(x, index = seq_len(nrow(x)))), listnum = seq_len(length(my_list)))
```

---

Or using `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
map2(my_list, seq_len(length(my_list)), ~mutate(.x, index = row_number(), listnum = .y))
#[[1]]
#   vec.1 vec.2 index listnum
#1     1     2     1       1
#2     2     3     2       1

#[[2]]
#   vec.2 vec.1 index listnum
#1     2     1     1       2
#2     3     2     2       2
```

Comment: I believe although, all other solutions does solve the problem. However, I found tidyverse solution very useful.

Comment: However, there is one issue that it didn't solve and that was if the list containing dataframes had some `NULL` list indices. The solution I had implemented involved figuring out which indices had `NULL` and then replace them with a dummy dataframe.

Comment: @Shoaibkhanz  It is not clear about the specific case.  But if there are NULL elements, you could do with a `if/else` condition i.e. `~if(is.null(.x)) NA else mutate(.x, index = row_number(), listnum = ..y))`

Answer (score 1):

You can modify your function like this:

```
funk <- function(i,x){
index <- seq(x[[i]])
listnum <- i
cbind(x[[i]],index,listnum)
}

new.dat <- lapply(1:length(my_list), funk,my_list)

#>new.dat
#[[1]]
#    vec.1 vec.2 index listnum
#1     1     2     1       1
#2     2     3     2       1

#[[2]]
#    vec.2 vec.1 index listnum
#1     2     1     1       2
#2     3     2     2       2
```

Answer (score 1):

This is does what you were after

```
new_list <- lapply(1:length(my_list), function(x) 
            my_list[[x]] <- cbind(my_list[[x]][1],
                        my_list[[x]][2],
                        index = 1:length(my_list[[x]][[2]]),
                        listnum = rep(x, length(my_list[[x]][2]))))

new_list
# [[1]]
#   vec.1 vec.2 index listnum
# 1     1     2     1       1
# 2     2     3     2       1

# [[2]]
#   vec.2 vec.1 index listnum
# 1     2     1     1       2
# 2     3     2     2       2
```

Just realized this can be done without having to create new dataset. Once following is run,`my_list` contain required result.

```
lapply(1:length(my_list), function(x) 
                my_list[[x]] <<- cbind(my_list[[x]][1],
                            my_list[[x]][2],
                            index = 1:length(my_list[[x]][[2]]),
                            listnum = rep(x, length(my_list[[x]][2]))))
```